# Hybridauth Twitter in yii framework

Tags: hybridauth

How to get User details twitter using hybridAuth extension in YII framework?

I am trying to get User Details in Hybridauth.Got Response 410. i dont know why?My Url in Ipaddress thats any problem for getting response from twitter?
My coding:

Comment: Sharing code will make it easier to help you...

Comment: $response = $this->api->get( 'account/verify_credentials.json' );
  // check the last HTTP status code returned
  if ( $this->api->http_code != 200 ){
   throw new Exception( "User profile request failed! {$this->providerId} returned an error. " . $this->errorMessageByStatus( $this->api->http_code ), 6 );
  } In this i ll struck redirect my url in that response.

Comment: function getUserProfile()
 {
  $response = $this->api->get( 'account/verify_credentials.json' );

  }